# Wrap a very long word in html table while converting to PDF

Tags: html, css, html-table, export-to-pdf

I want to wrap a long word in the table and convert that HTML to PDF. The problem is PDF converter only breaks a word when it encounters a white space.

Run the code snippet but the results are different when it gets converted to PDF.

```css
table {
  width: 90%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table td {
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="20%"> Email id: </td>
    <td width="30%"> Averyveryverylongtestemail@testmail.com </td>
    <td width="20%"> Age </td>
    <td width="20%"> 34 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="20%"> Gender </td>
    <td width="30%"> M </td>
    <td width="20%"> Unique ID </td>
    <td width="20%"> ABC564 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

After pdf conversion "Averyveryverylongtestemail@testmail.com" does not wrap instead overlaps with next column heading that is age.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: i think that is an issue with all "print to pdf" plugins for browser. Even Adobe's PDF plugin does that (using your example)

Comment: Can you say which package you're using, just in case?

Comment: One possible solution might be to cut up the long words in a couple of spans, like `<span>Averyveryver</span><span>ylongtestema</span><span>il@testmail.com</span>`. No idea if that would work though.

Comment: @Mr Lister: I am using XHTML to PDF library. Also, the data comes dynamically so cannot predict the length.

Comment: @Krati I understand, but I thought you could maybe cut it up into pieces of 10 characters before putting it in the HTML.